# Convert LocalDate in DD/MM/YYYY LocalDate

Tags: java, date, datetime, exception, localdate

I have a String with `DD/MM/YYYY` date format, and I want to check if the new date **is older than today**. I use `LocalDate.now();` However, i have an exception when I run this code:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter FORMATO_DIA = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/yyyy");

String otherDay = "02/12/1995";
LocalDate otherDay2 = LocalDate.parse(otherDay, FORMATO_DIA);
if (today.isBefore(otherDay2)){
    System.out.println("NICE");
}
```

Exception text:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02/12/1995' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=2, Year=1995, MinuteOfHour=12},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using `mm`, which stands for minutes. You must use `MM` for month