# Unable deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I am unable to deserialize Java-8-LocatDate because of following exception

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "15/09/1978": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate (java.time.format .DateTimeParseException) Text '15/09/1978' could not be parsed at index 0;

JSON request object containing Date is as follow

[
"employeeName" : "ABC XYZ",
     "birthDate"   : "15/09/1978"
]

I also tried to implement date deserialization by referring to URL [Deserialize Java 8 LocalDateTime with JacksonMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327970/deserialize-java-8-localdatetime-with-jacksonmapper/40330249)
However,following line of code

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/yyyy")) gave 
 following compilation error

Type mismatch: cannot convert from DateTimeFormatter to DateTimeFormat.ISO
in the line

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="EMP_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private long empId;

@Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
//below line gave compilation error ==> Type mismatch: cannot convert from DateTimeFormatter to DateTimeFormat.ISO
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/yyyy"))
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/mm/yyyy")
private LocalDate birthDate;
```

Please help me to resolve this issue,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert LocalDate in DD/MM/YYYY LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896499/convert-localdate-in-dd-mm-yyyy-localdate). Or maybe just somehow related.

Comment: Did you look into [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) yet?

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest is:

> sending the date in terms of milliseconds and changing that String in millisecond to date.

```
public class DateConverter {

    public static Date getDate(String sessionDate) {
        Long sessionOnDate = Long.parseLong(sessionDate);
        Date date = new Date(sessionOnDate);
        return date;
    }

    public static Long getTimeinMilliseconds(String myDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
        long millis = date.getTime();
        return millis;
    }

}
```

and in Entity you can simply have:

```
public class SessionDynamic
{
private Date sessionDate;
}
```

Let me know:)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Sure:) I will keep this one and also update the answer with the new edits @OleV.V.

Comment: I used - @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY").  I have Very little knowledge on java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I, also want to use @dateTimeFormat for deserialize value  `java.time.LocalDate` from String. Please help