# Problem with parse a LocalDateTime using java 8

Tags: parsing, java-8, java-time, localdate, datetime-parsing

I have this code, it's a simple string that I want to parse it to a LocalDateTime

```
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

    public class DateClass {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String dateRaw = "2019-05-03 7:05:03";        

            DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").toFormatter(); 

            LocalDateTime date= LocalDateTime.parse(dateRaw, dtf);
            System.out.println(date.toString());
        }

    }
```

And when y runing, I have the next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-05-03 7:05:03' could not be parsed at index 11
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at lectordeachvio.DateClass.main(DateClass.java:18)
```

what I doing wrong? and why has a fault with de space????

Comment: HH would be 07, but why are you using minutes twice?

Comment: Try with  '2019-05-03 07:05:03', as your date pattern

Comment: Upper case M for month and y for year

Comment: @Jens Strictly speaking `y` is not for year. `u` is for a (signed) year. `y` is for year of era. See [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)

Comment: It’s a good question. I think the expected result is clear, and the question has minimal. reproducible example and specific problem in the form of a well-formatted stack trace. Well done for a new Stacker. Also I think that this question may be useful for many future readers (if they can find it, I admit that it may be hard to search for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```

With this change your program outputs:

> 2019-05-03T07:05:03

- A single format pattern letter `H` will match hour of day in either 1 or two digits. That is, it will accept `7`, `07`, `13`, etc. Two `HH` on the other hand requires two digits like `07` or `13`, so `7` alone cannot be parsed. This was the reason for the exception that you got.
- Index 11 of your string is not where the space is. It is where the `7` is. Indices are 0-based.
- As others have mentioned you also need to use uppercase `MM` for month number. Lowercase `mm` is for minute of hour.
- As an aside you don’t necessarily need a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` for this case. `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` works OK.

Just out of curiosity, if your formatter is for parsing only, you may omit all repetitions of pattern letters. This works too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s");
```

Normally we would not want this, though. We’d prefer to validate that there *are* two digits for minutes and seconds, often also for month and day of month. Putting two pattern letters accomplishes that.

Partly related question about `mm` in the format pattern: [Convert LocalDate in DD/MM/YYYY LocalDate [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896499/convert-localdate-in-dd-mm-yyyy-localdate).

Comment: Thank you very much, to all of you and specially to you Ole.V.V. it works using as you said  
 String dateRaw = "2019-05-03 7:05:03";        
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd H:mm:ss").toFormatter(); 
        
Using this one:        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s");  
  I have a error

Comment: heres is the correct code:
`public class DateClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateRaw = "2019-05-03 12:05:03";        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd H:mm:ss").toFormatter(); 
        LocalDateTime date= LocalDateTime.parse(dateRaw, dtf);
        System.out.println("LocalDatetime ->"+date.toString());
        
        try {
         Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss").parse(dateRaw);
         System.out.println("Date ->"+ date1);
        }catch(Exception e){}}}`

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. Please for your own good don’t involve the `SimpleDateFormat` class, it’s a notorious troublemaker. And java,time gives you all the functionality you need and more. And don’t “swallow exceptions”: an empty catch block is a nono, it will hide errors from you, so it’s like coding blindfolded.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your pattern regards to month, because you use minutes:

> "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Please see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). And change in example date hour part from 7 to 07, as provided pattern.

Comment: Change the Date or the pattern?

Comment: Also i think there are duplicates on SO, so you should link zehn and not Write  a new answer.

Comment: @Jens You could easily be right about the dupe, so if you can find an original? I haven’t found any (yet).